# Positions off in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I have an oval that is positioned slightly lower on the right (Safari) than the left (Chrome) if you look carefully. Although this is quite minor, I would still like to know can this be fixed.
[image]

```
<body>
<div class="player">
<input type="button" id="specific" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"
onclick='window.open("<?php echo $specific; ?>")'>
//other stuff


.player
{
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 30px 10px 10px 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arial";
}

#specific
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15;
}
```

Comment: Could be a `box-sizing` issue

Comment: What is `.player` and what is `#specific`? Which one of these is the oval? Can you provide all the relevant markup please?